# How do I take one column from a data set and columns from anther data set to filter out a something specific?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am currently working in the nycflights13 package. I want to test one variable/column from one data set with a column from other data set.

nycflights13 has a data set called "planes" and another data set called "flights". Both data sets have a column variable called "tailnum" which is essentially the name of the plane. The age of the plane is located in "planes" while the place of origin for the flight is located in "flights". How would I write code in r that could tell me which is the oldest plane that flew out of JFK? Basically I need to take the column in "flights" that has the origins of the planes (where they are flying out of), filter out everything that isn't JKF, and then sort them descending by age, which is a column in "planes".

Comment: please post the code you currently have

Comment: Hi @KingKhan248, you question does not provide enough clarity about what you are trying to achieve. Sample data, expected results and code that you have tried would help other to help you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

How about this:

```
library(nycflights13)

library(conflicted)  # useful for dealing with functions in several packages
suppressMessages(conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr"))  # use filter from the dplyr package
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse)) # load tidyverse without messages 

data("flights") # from nycflights13 

theflights <- 
  flights %>% 
  filter(origin == "JFK") %>%  # get the filghts from JFK
  select (tailnum)  # only keep the airplane number

data("planes")  # from nycflights13 

# if you want the age 

inner_join(theflights, planes) %>%  # select the records from planes with matching tailnums defined above
  filter(year == min(year, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%  # get the oldest airplane
  select(year) %>%  # keep the year
  distinct() %>%  # remove duplicates
  mutate(age = 2013 - year) %>% # calculate the age in 2013
  pull(age)  # pull age into its own vector

# or

inner_join(theflights, planes) %>% 
  summarize(theYear = min(year, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(age = 2013 - theYear) %>% 
  pull(age)

# if you want the oldest airplane(s) tail numbers

inner_join(theflights, planes) %>%  # select the records from planes with matching tailnums defined above
  filter(year == min(year, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%  # you can use T or TRUE but TRUE is prefered 
  select(tailnum) %>% 
  distinct()


# if you want the oldest airplane(s) model
theModel <- 
  inner_join(theflights, planes) %>%  # select the records from planes with matching tailnums defined above
  filter(year == min(year, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%  # you can use T or TRUE but TRUE is prefered 
  select(model) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  pull()

# get all the airplanes of that model
DC7BFs <- 
  planes %>% 
  filter(model == theModel)
```

The `filter()` statement starts by finding the smallest (i.e., minimum) year after it drops the missing (i.e., NA) year values.  Then it finds every record that matches that year.

In theory you can use T or TRUE for logic checks.  However, TRUE is recommended by the R [style guide](https://style.tidyverse.org/syntax.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.  Wouldn't this code return the age of the plane in 2013? What i was asking was how I would return the tailnum of the oldest plane to originate from JFK. Also, can you explain "filter(year == min(year, na.rm = T))". I have never seen or used na.rm, and I'm guessing "T" is "True"?

Comment: I added code to select the tail numbers(s) of the airplanes that are the oldest.  T does mean TRUE.  Sorry that is bad form on my part.  If that answers the question, please  click off the green checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: I am so sorry, I guess I confused myself as well. I don't want to find out how many of that exact plane (ie that tailnum) flew out of JFK, I want to know how many of that MODEL flew out of JFK. So basically, I want to take that plane with tailnum = "N381AA", then find what the model of that plane is (data for models of planes is located in the "planes" data set), and then finally find out how many planes of that model flew out of JFK. I hope that is more clear.

Comment: I added code to get all the airplanes of that model.  If that is the solution, please check the green check.  If it is helpful check the upward pointing triangle... or both :)

Comment: What that gives me is a tibble 1 x 9 of just that one plane with tailnum = N381AA. How do I count all of the planes of that model that have flown out of JFK? The output should just be the number of planes of that specific model, with only the ones that flew out out JFK being filtered in.  I tried the tally function: tally(DC7BFs) but that only returned a value of 1.

Comment: I believe that is the only one with that model.